# javafx webEngine.print empty pages at the end

Tags: javafx-8, javafx-webengine

I'm trying to print my webEngine with print method, and an issue I have is an extra empty page after all the content is printed. I wonder what it could be or how to troubleshoot that issue?

```
public class JSPrintHook {
    public void print() {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
        if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(webView.getScene().getWindow())) {
                webView.getEngine().print(job);
                job.endJob();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @Selim, no, if I remember correctly, I just gave up on this one and told the customer that it's a way it is :(

Comment: I might actually have found a solution myself yesterday. I had paddings / margins at the bottom of certain elements that were located at the bottom of the page. So javafx printed this invisible space onto a page. After changing the structure this problem went away for me!

Answer (score 0):

It can be a thread handling problem, if you use WebEngine without javafx.application.Application (eg. integrate JavaFX to Swing UI). In this case you should use Platform.runLater().
For example:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // print
    }
});
```

Comment: No, I use it within Application. It was quite a while ago, need to check if I've already found a workaround. Thank you, Zoli